# Meaning of optical icon size in generic icon generator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm using [Generic icon generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example) tool to resize my image which i want to use as background for a linerlayout container in my android app.

the issue is i can't really understand the meaning of **optical icon size** parameter. and whether i should  modify it's default value. my image is 594 X 583 px

i have googled for the meaning but have found none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, what you refer to is the size of the icon in dip, which as default is set in 24dip. Following the Android guidelines and depending on the use you will give to this icon, you will need to define it. As said, the values set by default by the generator are the default ones defined by google. So using them like that you should no have any trouble.

Comment: since my image is going to be used as background, i have set it to maximum which is 200 dip.

Comment: Then I wouldn't recomend you using this tool. If you just want to resize an image to use it as background, you should be able to do it using photoshop or tools like that. The icon generator produces a square icon to use it as icon, but doesn't give you the chance to change the px values independently.